# Switching between stripe checkouts for platform account and connected account (to save card on platform account)

Tags: stripe-payments

I am using stripe connect.

I am using strong customer authentication and payment methods

I want customers to be able to save their card on my platform account so that I can then charge their cards on all connected accounts.

For example, if a user ticks a checkbox stating 'save my card for future use', I want to save their card on my platform account.

However, if this checkbox is not ticked, I want to charge the customer of the connected account instead.

I am having difficulties switching between my platform account and the connected account on my front end.

I have saved to instances of Stripes checkout to variables:

```
  let checkoutFormConnected = (
    this.state.userEvent.organiser.stripeAccountID !== "" && (
      <StripeProvider
        apiKey={process.env.REACT_APP_API_STRIPE_PUBLISH}
        stripeAccount={this.state.userEvent.organiser.stripeAccountID}
      >
        <Elements>
          <CheckoutForm/>
        </Elements>
      </StripeProvider>
    )
  );


 let checkoutFormNotConnected = (
    this.state.userEvent.organiser.stripeAccountID !== "" && (
      <StripeProvider
        apiKey={process.env.REACT_APP_API_STRIPE_PUBLISH}
      >
        <Elements>
          <CheckoutForm />
        </Elements>
      </StripeProvider>
    )
  );
```

and I am displaying them depending on whether the checkbox for saving the card is ticked:

```
{this.state.checkBoxes.saveCard ? checkoutFormNotConnected : checkoutFormConnected}
```

However, it appears that whichever checkoutForm is first rendered remains even after I switch between the two checkoutForm variables.

I have tested to ensure that I am switching between these two options by displaying prop values on screen.

When the connected account checkout appears on screen first, and then switches to the platform account checkout, when I try to save the card on the platform account I get the error: `"No such setupintent: 'seti_1Hw8LXCFzSpFw85fowNQm634'"`

This is displaying because the backend created the setup intent on the connected account, even though I switched to the variable holding the checkoutForm for the platform account.

It appears that the checkoutForm won't re-render once it has rendered on the page.

For reference my backend code is

```
const customer = await stripe.customers.create();

const Intent = stripe.setupIntents.create({
  customer: customer.id,
});

const UpdateCustomer = User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.body.purchaserID, {
  stripeCustomerID: customer.id,
});

Promise.all([Intent, UpdateCustomer]).then((data) => {
  res.send({
    customerID: customer.id,
    clientSecret: data[0].client_secret,
  });
});
```

The [docs](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-during-payment) only show how to save a card during payment for accounts that are not connected.

I have also coded this so that the platform account appears first on the page. Then I can save the card on the platform account and charge it in the future. I do this by cloning payment methods But when the checkoutForm changes to charge a new card (on a connected account) I get the same error about payment intents (because it is trying to set it up on the platform account)

How can I re-render the stripe checkout to switch between the platform account and the connected account?

Update: this works!:

```
      <StripeProvider
        apiKey={process.env.REACT_APP_API_STRIPE_PUBLISH}
        stripeAccount={this.state.userEvent.organiser.stripeAccountID || undefined}
        key={this.state.checkBoxes.saveCard || 'platform'}
      >
```

Comment: On first glance, it's not obvious why your code wouldn't re-render the Checkout form when the stripe account updates. Could I have you try an alternate approach of using React's key prop to trigger an update if the stripeAccount changes? Something like: http://pastie.org/p/5T1ieoT5JTE52DTNXhhwZr

Comment: Thank you! This works! Could you talk me through the code so I understand it? I've pasted the code that works at the bottom of my question. For the key value I used the part of state that changes when the save card checkbox is ticked. When I don't include || 'platform' in key it doesn't work. Why is this? Why does it need random string? I assume stripeAccount is equal to this.state.userEvent.organiser.stripeAccountID until the key changes and it is then equal to undefined. Do I understand this right?

Comment: If you would like to post your fix as a solution I'd be delighted to accept it as the answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution to this would be to use React's special `key` prop to force the checkout form to re-mount whenever the Stripe account changes. For example:

```
<StripeProvider
  apiKey={process.env.REACT_APP_API_STRIPE_PUBLISH}
  stripeAccount={this.state.userEvent.organiser.stripeAccountID || undefined}
  key={this.state.userEvent.organiser.stripeAccountID || 'platform'}
>
  <Elements>
    <CheckoutForm/>
  </Elements>
</StripeProvider>
```

The `key` prop in React is typically only used when rendering elements in an array. The idea is that you add unique keys to each element in the array to help React keep track of what elements changes and which ones don't. React encourages you to add a `key` prop whenever rendering a list of items, but it isn't strictly necessary unless the order of those list items change. You can read more on that here:

- https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys
- https://kentcdodds.com/blog/understanding-reacts-key-prop

The reason I added a `|| 'platform'` to the value of the key prop is to trigger a re-mount when `this.state.userEvent.organiser.stripeAccountID` is undefined or falsey. I'm making the assumption that `this.state.userEvent.organiser.stripeAccountID` will be falsey if you don't want to collect the payment method as the connected account. React doesn't treat falsey values as valid keys, so without that `|| 'platform'` there would be no perceived change, and no re-mount.